# My toggler is not working. I have tried placing js cdn in top and bottom both but didn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I tried placing the js cdn in top and it did not work. I was trying to make my navbar responsive and used toggler. The navbar became responsive but the toggler button is not working.

[image]

Here is my code, the hamburger menu is not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="title">
    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Tindog</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="NssavbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
   </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66312595/6127393

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Bootstrap V5 it's `data-bs-toggle` not `data-toggle`, plus you needed a "#" to point the target to an ID not a class. Lastly you had a typo "NssavbarSupportedContent" should be "navbarSupportedContent".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="title">
    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Tindog</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
   </section>
 </body>
</html>
```